# How editing html and javascript of a website makes it vulnerable?

Tags: web-application, xss, ctf

I was practicing web pentesting on [this level of ctf2](http://ctf.infosecinstitute.com/ctf2/exercises/ex1.php) and I was supposed to edit the HTML and the Javascript to get rid of the input validation and `< >` sanitization. I succeded after looking up the solution elsewhere.

Now what I don't understand is why modify the HTMLand the Javascript. The changes will be lost once the page is reloaded, so how does that makes it dangerous? Is this how XSS is done, by editing the HTML/Javascript and injecting `script` tags to the input fields? And how does it threaten real users?

I know the challenge was 'simple' and there are no users who are threatened, but is it the same concept in real life?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you described is not XSS or a threat to anyone else. And note that CTFs are not an example of pentesting or how one assesses websites. They are highly contrived exercises that exercise skills and present logic puzzles.